# PHP proxy ajax doesn't return a response for POST

Tags: php, ajax, curl, forms

I am using the following PHP proxy:

```
//Store the URL
$jURL = $_POST['jURL'];
//Store the POST data
$jData = $_POST['post_data'];

//And let cURL work it's magic.
$ch = curl_init();

//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $jURL);
//Enable POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//Use the $pData array as the POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jData);

//curl_exec automatically writes the data returned
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```

and I am calling it by:

```
  var dataString = { 'Contact': Contact, 'address1': address1, 'address2': address2, 'city': city, 'state': state, 'zip': zip, 'Phone1': primPhone, 'Phone2': secPhone, 'email': email,
                               'key2': key2, 'key5': key5, 'uhsgradyr': uhsgradyr, 'uhighlevel': uhighlevel, 'ucourseint': ucourseint, 'uCampaignID': uCampaignID, 'utextperm':utextperm,
                               'uleaddate': uleaddate, 'uleadtime':uleadtime};

                var postData = {jURL: 'http://test.com/candidate_test.php', postData: dataString};
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "proxy.php",
                        data: postData,
                        success: function(data) {
                                 window.location = "thankyou.php";
                        },
                        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                                 console.log(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                });
```

The issue is that why am I still not getting any response back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I actually went to the site.. you need to replace some javascript:

```
$(".Submit").click(function() {
```

should be

```
$('#form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
```

In the present code, you never say "stop form submission and react to ajax", which is what `ev.preventDefault()` does for you.

---

Old answer:
You should set one more option:

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

to make sure `$response` actually contains the curl's response. See the documentation on [`curl_exec()`](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues).

Comment: thanks, did you see anything else wrong? I am a bit confused on what the dataString I have there

Comment: @aherlambang: did you make sure that the "php proxy" works? I.e. replace everything from `$_POST` with your own variables and calling the php file by itself. Also, make sure that you inspect the ajax call via Chrome's Network inspector or the Network tab in Firefox Firebug.

Comment: I put the proxy in the URL adityaherlambang.com/proxy.php and when I do a curl to that giving the URL it spits out a response. You can try curl -d "jURL=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.degreeamerica.com%2Fcandidate_test.php" adityaherlambang.com/proxy.php

Comment: Ok good! What does the browser say about the ajax call? (The second part of my previous comment)

Comment: it gives no response and error.. again, you can try it live at adityaherlambang.com

Comment: hey dude, I thought your answer worked.. but even if I put in ev.preventDefault it still posts the value although forms empty

Answer (score 1):

That might be because you're setting `jData = $_GET['post_data'];` instead of `jData = $_POST['post_data'];`

In your jQuery `.ajax()` call you're setting `type: "POST"` so the data will be in `$_POST` not `$_GET`.

Comment: did that and it didn't help, also will the php proxy above is supposed to create an AJAX response?

Comment: When you say "not getting a response back" do you mean in your PHP proxy script or the HTML page? If it's in the HTML page, that's not surprising since you never output anything from your PHP file. [`curl_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) doesn't output anything on its own.

Comment: it's in the HTML page.. I can see the output in the PHP proxy script.. so how do I output in my PHP file in the proxy script? I tried to echo the curl_exec, but I still am not seeing anything

Comment: PHP file? You mention nothing about a PHP file in the question (apart from the proxy PHP code. Please update the question with the relevant information. What are you trying to achieve? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: I meant the PHP proxy code, that's all the PHP I have... what I am getting can be seen at adityaherlambang.com, try filling out the form and see in firebug there's no response.. the proxy code is above.. please advice